# Change the title in index.rst generated by Sphinx AutoAPI

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, api-documentation

I am looking for a way to rename the title in index.rst.

[AutoAPI](https://sphinx-autoapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) generates a documentation of modules inside a directory `..\docs\source\_autoapi` with `index.rst` file as follows:

```
API Reference
=============

This page contains auto-generated API reference documentation [#f1]_.

.. toctree::
   :titlesonly:

   /_autoapi/moduleA/index
   /_autoapi/moduleB/index

.. [#f1] Created with `sphinx-autoapi <https://github.com/readthedocs/sphinx-autoapi>`_
```

Is there a way to rename the title "API Reference" inside the `index.rst` file when using AutoAPI?

Comment: https://sphinx-autoapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/how_to.html#how-to-customise-the-index-page

Comment: Found these tutorials pretty nice and had helped a lot. They explain how to manually add and set up Sphink AutoAPI's default template: - [Generating beautiful Python API documentation with Sphinx AutoAPI](https://bylr.info/articles/2022/05/10/api-doc-with-sphinx-autoapi/#setting-up-templates) - [Generating beautiful Python API documentation with Sphinx AutoAPI and Jinja (a template engine) by Antoine Beyeler](https://gdevops.gitlab.io/tuto_documentation/doc_generators/sphinx/contributed_extensions/sphinx_autoapi/antoine_beyler/antoine_beyler.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy the template files and python folder of the official autoapi git located at https://github.com/readthedocs/sphinx-autoapi
I place my files/folders in the _templates folder of sphinx. so the folder path would look something like

```
src/docs/_templates/autoapi/
```

after this you need to add

```
autoapi_template_dir = "_templates/autoapi"
```

to your sphinx conf.py file after the extensions section. Now you can edit the index.rst to fit your needs, in your case you would change API Reference to YOUR TITLE HERE.