# Changing Labels on Sphinx html page

Tags: html, documentation, python-sphinx, myst

I am using **myst-parser** and **autoapi** to generate the html page for my src folder. Everything is working fine, except I can't seem to find an option to change the labels on the left menu other than changing the html files manually.

I wonder if there is any option to write on the conf.py or index.md to set a different name for the documentation of my src folder.

As per image bellow, I just would like to change the name **API Reference** to something else.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/51W7o.png]

This is how my **conf.py** file looks like

```
extensions = [
    "myst_parser",
    "autoapi.extension",
    "sphinx.ext.napoleon",
    "sphinx.ext.viewcode",
]
autoapi_dirs = ["../src"]

exclude_patterns = ['_build', 'Thumbs.db', '.DS_Store']

html_theme = 'sphinx_rtd_theme'
```

and this is how my **index.md** looks like:

```
{include} ../README.md


{toctree}
:maxdepth: 1
:hidden:

autoapi/index
```

Comment: That looks like the title of the page. Change the title in your source file to what you want.

Comment: Seems to be the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/q/73068271/407651